# how to axis2 soap services packaged as *.aar

Tags: quarkus, apache-axis

we are migrating code from j2ee and we have a lot of soap services built using Axis2 and packages as *.aar.
we managed to package them and make it work in dev mode but for some reason in production mod Axis2 does not found them.

We have multi jar application and the *.aar files are packaged in jar under resources\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF\services. but it seems like production class loader ignore them